# Does Backbone.js have something like 'rake routes' from Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, architecture, routes

Is there an easy way to see all the routes my Backbone.js application has built while it's running?

Ruby on Rails has `rake routes`, which shows things like this:

```
    unicorns GET    /unicorns(.:format)          unicorns#index
             POST   /unicorns(.:format)          unicorns#create
 new_unicorn GET    /unicorns/new(.:format)      unicorns#new
edit_unicorn GET    /unicorns/:id/edit(.:format) unicorns#edit
     unicorn GET    /unicorns/:id(.:format)      unicorns#show
             PUT    /unicorns/:id(.:format)      unicorns#update
             DELETE /unicorns/:id(.:format)      unicorns#destroy
```

Does Backbone have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check a router prototype/instance `routes` property to get all statically declared routes. So if you're not generating them programmatically, you'll get the cleanest output as so:

```
console.log( router.routes );
```

If you're using `this.route()` to dynamically add routes, then you should check on the `Backbone.History` object, this will be the complete list of routes used inside your app; although the output is a little bit messiers (routes are compiled to regexp, etc).

```
console.log( Backbone.history.handlers );
```

Note that this property ain't documented, so there's no garantee it will be kept in future version of Backbone. I'd only use it for debugging purpose.

Comment: The only properties on the router instance are the ones I've added and router._callbacks. Backbone v0.9.2

Comment: Check inside the prototype

Comment: Oh, that thing. That doesn't register routes made with `this.route( routeName, routeName, callback)'

Comment: You're right, didn't checked this use case when I answered. I edited my answer with additonnal information for dynamic routes.